# Proof termination of a function with (well-founded) induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, induction

I need your help with the following proof:

We define a function $f : N \times N \to N$ with:

$$f(x, y) =
     \begin{cases}
       y + 1 &  x = 0 \\
       f(x - 1, 1) &  x > 0, y = 0 \\
       f(x - 1, f(x, y - 1)) &  x > 0,y > 0
     \end{cases}
$$

I need to prove now that this functions terminates for all $ (m, n) \in  N \times N$.

My approach would be with well-founded induction since the set $N \times N$ is well-founded. But I do now know what my base cases are, so I cannot get started.

Any help or hint would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You need to set this up as a proof by induction over $x$ ... but inside of that you'll need induction over $y$. So:

Claim: For any $x$ and $y$: $P(x,y)$, where $P(x,y)$ is shorthand for the claim that $f(x,y)=k$ for some number $k$ which is established by computing $k$ in a finite number of steps following the recursive definition of $f(x,y)$

Proof: By (weak) induction over $x$

Base: x = 0. We want to show that for any $y$: $P(x,y)$. Well: For any $y$, we have $f(0,y) = y+1$ obtained in 1 step, so we're good. Check!

Step: Suppose $x$ is some number $n>0$ and suppose (inductive hypotheses X) it is true that for any $y$: $P(n,y)$. Now we need to show that for any $y$: $P(n+1,y)$.

OK, we'll prove the latter by (weak) induction over $y$:

Base: $y = 0$. $f(n+1,0) = f(n,1)$. By Inductive Hypothesis X: $P(x,1)$, so we're good. Check!

Step: Suppose $y$ is some number $m>0$ and suppose (inductive hypotheses Y) it is true that $P(n+1,m)$. Now we need to show that $P(n+1,m+1)$.

Well: $f(n+1,m+1) = f(n,f(n+1,m))$. By inductive Hypothesis Y we have that $f(n+1,m)=k$ where $k$ is established after finitely many steps. Thus, after some finite number of steps, we are down to evaluating $f(n,k)$. But by Inductive Hypothesis X, that takes some finite number of steps as well, and so $f(n+1,m+1) = f(n,f(n+1,m))$ can be evaluated in some finite number of steps (since the sum of two finite numbers is still finite). Check!

This concludes the 'inside' inductive proof, and so now we have established that for any $y$: $P(n+1,y)$.

But that concludes the Step of the 'outside' inductive proof (check!) and so now we have established that for any $x$ and $y$: $P(x,y)$.

ADDENDUM

Sorry!  I now understand you want a proof using well-founded induction over $N * N$ as a whole.  OK, then let's first define the well-ordering we are going to use, so let's define:

$(p,q) < (r,s)$ iff $(p < r) \lor (p = r \land q < s)$

It is easy to verify that this $<$ is a well-ordering, and so we can use well-founded induction to prove the claim that for any $(x,y)$: $P(x,y)$ (as defined earlier)

Base: you actually have a whole bunch of base cases: all pairs $(0,y)$ for any $y \in N$. Clearly, $P(0,y)$ is true for any $(0,y)$, so we're good. Check!

Step: Take any  $(x,y)$ with $x > 0$, and suppose (inductive hypothesis) that for any $(p,q)< (x,y)$ we have that $P(p,q)$. Now one of two cases holds:

If $y=0$ then $f(x,y) = f(x-1,y)$, and since $(x-1,y)<(x,y)$, by inductive hypothesis we have $P(x-1,y)$ i.e. $f(x-1,y)$ will be determined in a finite number $n$ steps, and that means that $f(x,y)$ is determined in $n+1$ steps, i.e. still finite, and hence $P(x,y)$.

If $y>0$, then $f(x,y) = f(x-1,f(x,y-1))$. Now, $(x,y-1)<(x,y)$, and hence by inductive hypothesis $f(x-1,y)=k$ will be determined in some finite number of steps $n_1$. Also, $(x-1,k) < (x,y)$, and so by inductive hypothesis we have $P(x-1,k)$ i.e. $f(x-1,k)$ will be determined in a finite number $n_2$  steps. Hence, $f(x,y)$ will be determined in $n_1+n_2$ steps, i.e. a finite number of steps.

NOTE: I first tried to define $(p,q) < (r,s)$ iff $(p < r \land q \le s) \lor (p \le r \land q < s)$, and while that is another(and more intuitive)  well-ordering, it's not going to make this inductive proof work, since in the step and in the case of $y>0$ you can't guarantee that $(x-1,k) < (x,y)$ (in fact, that would be plain false!)

Comment: Thank you very much, but is this proof also possible with 'well-founded' induction since I do now really understand the concept of well-founded induction?!

Comment: You mean given that we can define a well-ordering on $N*N$ by e.g. defining $(p,q) < (r,s)$ iff $(p < r \land q  \le s) \lor (p \le r \land q < s)$ (which would be a partial ordering, but that's ok for a well-ordering)? Yeah, that should work. And in that case you have a whole bunch of base cases: all pairs $(0,y)$ for any $y \in N$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that function $f$ does **not** terminate for all elements of $\mathbb N\times\mathbb N$.

Let $m$ be the smallest nonnegative integer such that some $k\in\mathbb N$ exists such that $f$ does not terminate for $\langle m,k\rangle$.

Then secondly let $n$ be the smallest nonnegative integer such that $f$ does not terminate for $\langle m,n\rangle$.

But looking at the prescription of $f(m,n)$ we now find quite easily that $f$ terminates for $\langle m,n\rangle$ after all, and a contradiction is found.

Final conclusion:

Our assumption was wrong, so function $f$ does terminate for all elements of $\mathbb N\times\mathbb N$.